# Deriving from a Form and making InitializeComponent /Components to protected

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two Forms that share a lot of functionality, so I've decided to factor it out into a base Form class. 
However, among the things I'll have to change is bringing the auto-generated `System.ComponentModel.Container components` and turn the `InitializeComponent` class into `virtual`
so that each inheriting class can call its overriding method.

I saw some issues on-line saying that you should never call virtual methods inside constructors, which makes sense, since the class is built from base->least inherited.
I also thought of keeping `InitializeComponents` `private`, but I still need to initialize the `components`, so I need to make it `protected` at least.

**Are there any pitfalls** in this technique I should be careful of?
(out-of-curiosity: If I have multiple private methods at different levels of the Hierarchy will reflection burst into flames?)

In short, I need to factor out a base class for two Forms so that I have this:

```
class FormBase 
{
    protected IContainer components;
    private void InitalizeComponents() {/*common stuff*/}
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
}

class FormA :FormBase
{
    private void InitalizeComponents() {/*specialized stuff*/}
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
}

class FormB :FormBase
{
    private void InitalizeComponents() {/*specialized stuff*/}
    public FormB()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that Visual Studio, at least the version I tried this on several years ago, does not support a derived Form class in the IDE. So the one time I looked into it I quickly gave up on the whole idea.

Comment: If you mean in the WYSIWYG, then yea (sort of). The base has to be in a dll to use it. As with custom controls.